# Visual Studio allows enum to be passed in for a bool

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Using VS 2019 and I know 'enum class' should be used today, but the code base I'm working in has a lot of enums defined in the style A below. The problem is programmers (me) calling DoSomething(...) passing an enum instead of a bool and VS does not complain with a warning or error.

I have tried raising the warning level but VS still not catching it. Short of rewriting a lot of code, is there any way to force VS to treat this as an error?

```
typedef enum A {a1,a2} A;

enum class B {b1, b2};

void DoSomething(bool aBool){}

int main()
{
    DoSomething(a1); //compiler does NOT catches a1 is not of type bool
    DoSomething(B::b1); //compiler catches B::b1 is not of type bool
}
```

Comment: Old-style enums are implicitly convertable to int, which itself can evaluate to a bool (anything non-zero is true), so this is not an error. The new enum class types do not do this. Change your enums to enum class.

Comment: @jkb: old-style enums are int no conversion needed.

Comment: @engf-010, https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/enum#dcl.enum-5

Comment: `bool operator!(B b) { return b == B::b1; }` then you can do `DoSomething(!!B::b1);`, which is a JavaScript idiom.  Otherwise, you can do `void DoSomething(B b) { DoSomething(b == B::b2); }` thunk function.  Or `bool to_bool(B b) { return b == B::b2; }` if that's your cup of tea, and `DoSomething(to_bool(B::b1))`.

Comment: @Eljay I think this is the opposite of what the OP asked for.

Comment: Create a DoSomething overload that takes an enum and put a failed static assert in it.

Comment: @PaulSanders • Oopsies, I misread that, you are correct.  `void DoSomething(A);` and leave it unimplemented would trip an error.  Or `template <typename T> void DoSomething(T);` and leave that unimplemented would trip an error for anything non-`bool`.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use a wrapper around `bool` which is constructible from `bool` but not from `int`, as the `enum` converts to `int` the wrapper wouldn't be constructible from the `enum`:

```
enum A {a1,a2};

struct Bool
{
    Bool(bool b)
    : value(b)
    {}

    Bool(int i) = delete;

    bool value;
    operator bool() { return value; }
};

void DoSomething(Bool aBool){
    if (aBool) {}
}

int main()
{
    DoSomething(true);
    DoSomething(a1);
}
```

Of course it is easier just to use `enum class`, this is exactly the kind of problem it was designed to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestions. The best solution is to refactor to 'enum class'. the second best, for my situation, was to use Clang-Tidy which will catch this mistake. I made two changes in the Project Properties->Code Analysis page;

1. Enable Clang-Tidy. It's default value was No
   [image]
2. Enable a specific Clang-Tidy option. A list of all option [here](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/)
   [image]

The code in my original post will now show a warning after build which is what I was expecting in the first place.

```
int main()
{
    DoSomething(a1); //Warning readability-implicit-bool-conversion implicit conversion 'A' -> bool    
}
```